# get string value from nullable array

Tags: typescript

I need get string value from nullable array:

```
const nullableArray: Array<string | null> = ['some string'];

const myValue: string = nullableArray[0] ? nullableArray[0] : ''; // compiler error
```

Working but ugly solution:

```
const myNullableValue: string | null = nullableArray[0];
const myValue: string = myNullableValue ? myNullableValue : '';
```

Does exist more elegant way?

Comment: there is no compile error on your first code see this, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avixi7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
const myValue:string = nullableArray[0] || "";
```